# Does Inertia "conflict" Entropy?

Tags: entropy, inertia

Earth continues to spin because of inertia. Does this fact "conflict" the entropy of the universe? Since the tendence is towards disorder, how is Inertia of planets Spin related to Entropy?

Comment: Disorder is a bad way to describe entropy I heard.

Comment: one way to understand entropy is to list all the possible states, and then usually you will find one (or few) configuration(s) enormously outnumbers the others. hence even if the system is not in that most probable configuration, it will "tend" to "evolve" toward that configurations. The whole thing is what we call the law of entropy (very roughly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the earth continues to spin because of the conservation of angular momentum; the conservation of angular momentum does not conflict in any way with the entropy of the universe. The physical mechanisms at work in the earth which slowly convert angular momentum into dissipative tidal dynamics and thence into frictional heat can themselves be considered an illustration of the thermodynamic principles that describe entropy.

Answer (score 2):

Entropy is a measure of our ignorance of a thermodynamic system, or in its precise mathematical form (Boltzmann's entropy formula), $S=k\log \Omega$, where $\Omega$ is the number of microstates of the system corresponding to a given macrostate specification of the system. If the system is closed, the 2nd law of thermodynamics says that entropy tend to a maximum, on average.

The classical system of a chunk of mass rotating in free space at zero-temperature (which is what one usually assumes in standard mechanics problems) has identically zero entropy, $S=0$ - the system is completely specified. Moreover it will remain at $S=0$, in accordance with the 2nd law of thermodynamics.

Of course, we could get more and more realistic, e.g. assuming the chunk of mass isn't at $T=0$, assuming radiation is relevant, assuming the mass has internal structure, assuming it is not a closed system, etc. That would make the problem more complicated.